# Parallel Extensions Equivalent in Java

Tags: java, .net, parallel-extensions

I have some experience using parallel extensions in .Net development, but I was looking at doing some work in Java that would benefit from an easy to use parallelism library. Does the JVM offer any comparable tools to parallel-extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some limited support in [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package since java 5, but full supports are [java 7 feature](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/#jsr166).

Answer (score 3):

You should become familiar with the [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/j2se/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. It has simple and robust primitives for parallel programming upon which to base higher-level libraries. One example of such a library is [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org), which has [an easy-to-use module for parallel programming](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/2.20/javadoc/fj/control/parallel/ParModule.html).

For example, here is the canonical MapReduce example written using Functional Java. It counts the number of words in a set of documents, assuming documents are Streams of characters:

```
public static long countWords(final List<Stream<Character>> documents,
                              final ParModule m)
{ return m.parFoldMap(documents,
                      new F<Stream<Character>, Long>()
                      { public Long f(final Stream<Character> document)
                        { return (long)fromStream(document).words().length(); }},
                      longAdditionMonoid)
          .claim(); }
```

To instantiate ParModule, you give it a parallel Strategy. You can implement your own Strategies, or use one that's supplied. Here's one that uses a fixed pool of 16 threads:

```
ExecutorService pool = newFixedThreadPool(16);
ParModule m = parModule(executorStrategy(pool));
```

You need the following imports for the example above:

```
import fj.F;
import fj.data.Stream;
import fj.control.parallel.ParModule;
import static fj.control.parallel.ParModule.parModule;
import static fj.pre.Monoid.longAdditionMonoid;
import static fj.data.LazyString.fromStream;     
import static fj.control.parallel.Strategy.executorStrategy;
import static java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
```

Answer (score 2):

you should definetely try Ateji Parralel extensions.
http://www.ateji.com/multicore/

Comment: Unfortunately, they went out of business. The first lecture from http://yuiblog.com/crockford/ explains why. In addition, there is no IntelliJ plugin for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the site for the JSR166 working group, who wrote the new concurrency classes for Java 7.

http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/

There are 2 packages listed: jsr166y (the new concurrency classes for Java 7) and extra166y (various classes that for one reason or another will not be included).

One of the classes in extra166y, `ParallelArray` is very useful. It automatically parallelizes binary searches, merge-sorts, etc.