# Java parallel execution on multicore

Tags: java, parallel-extensions

i would like to know whether exist a way to parallelize queries in Java (or there is framework or a library) like in C# and Linq:

```c#
var query = from item in source.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
        where Compute(item) > 42
        select item;
```

and if i can't parallelize queries if i can do something like this in c# (a for each parallelized) :

```c#
  Parallel.ForEach(files, currentFile =>
        {
            // The more computational work you do here, the greater  
            // the speedup compared to a sequential foreach loop. 
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(currentFile);
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(currentFile);

            bitmap.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
            bitmap.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(newDir, filename));

            // Peek behind the scenes to see how work is parallelized. 
            // But be aware: Thread contention for the Console slows down parallel loops!!!
            Console.WriteLine("Processing {0} on thread {1}", filename,
                                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        }
```

please if you post any framework or library, can you tell me the experience that you had with it ? 
thx for your time.

about c# and linq you can find here the documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425.aspx

Comment: It is coming in Java 8 (i.e. next year) - until then you need to write it yourself or find a library...

Comment: :) thx the next year is on the door :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct translation. Firstly Java doesn't have LINQ nor does it have any standard parallel collection classes.

[GPars](http://gpars.codehaus.org/) is perhaps closest fit.

Note that while it is targeted at groovy it's API is perfectly usable from java

Comment: JDK8 should see the apparition of Collection.parallel() and Spliterable, though.

Comment: @frank don't think there is much argument on that front.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Fork/Join Framework](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/fj.pdf) can help you ? Here is [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)

Comment: this can be good for recursive tasks but dose not help me to improve the performance of a query and it dose not so simple like to write a keyword as in c#

Comment: and i can't extends the execution to more threads in a simple way so i would like something of more simple to use

Comment: counts of threads != improving of speed, you should understand it, but you can use, just ExecutionService to submit new tasks (queries) as paralel process.

Comment: @frank and judging to this thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077584/parallel-extensions-equivalent-in-java I am right

Comment: F/J isn't really suited for [IO bound tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206318/is-javas-fork-and-join-thread-pool-is-good-for-executing-io-bound-task)